Filamnet V3 con función v2 - ->visibleWhen('matriculacion', true) inexistente
tengo una consulta mas que nada porque mire la documentacion no esta dicha funcion
el codigo es el siguiente
Como se oculta los componentes dependiendo del estado de los selectores Toggle
el código en Filament es
 Forms\Components\Toggle::make('matriculacion')
            ->label('Se Cobrara Matriculacion')
            ->required(),
        Forms\Components\Toggle::make('cuota')
            ->label('Se cobrara Cuota')
            ->required(),
            Forms\Components\Toggle::make('cobro_certificado')
            ->label('Se Cobrara Certificado')
                ->required()
                ,
            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('costo_matricula')
            ->label('Costo de la Matriculacion')
                ->required()
                ->mask(RawJs::make('$money($input)'))
                ->stripCharacters(',')
      
                ->numeric(),
 
            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('costo_cuota')
            ->label('Costo de la Cuota')
                ->required()
                ->mask(RawJs::make('$money($input)'))
                ->numeric(),


            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('costo_certificado')
                ->required()
                ->mask(RawJs::make('$money($input)'))
                ->numeric()
                ,

anteriormente existía en filament  ->visibleWhen('matriculacion', true), pero esta función ya no existe en la versión 3, tienen alguna idea de como hacerlo ?
Saludos
